# single touch on touchscreen results in double click

Tags: raspbian-jessie, touchscreen

I can't seem to do a single click with a single touch with my 7" touchscreen I recently attached to my Rpi (Raspbian-Jessie).

Any ideas as to why it is registering a single touch as a double click? It makes it nearly impossible to use things like Kivy apps.

The screen I am using can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0153R2A9I).

The Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B) I am using can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C6EQNNK).

They are connected as follows:
[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the make and model of the touch screen, and a brief outline of how it's connected to the Pi?

Comment: Apologies for lack of detail. I have now amended the question.

Comment: Just a quick ping to see if you had a chance to take another look.

Comment: I found booting up in CLI mode and starting the app from the command line removed the double tap sequence.

Comment: Great work! I'd be happy to upvote any working solution if you write it up as an answer.

Comment: Done! =) Though I now have another issue over at a https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67787/touch-commands-backed-up-on-kivy-touch-screen-rpi-when-usb-plugged-in if you'd be kind to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple work around as it seems to be [problematic for some others](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3640) (though for different reasons). Since the app is the only thing I will be running on the Pi, I decided to boot in CLI mode which just means it boots to the terminal rather than the OS GUI environment. I then just went to the folder with the program and ran `python main.py'.

If you want to just turn the Pi on and have it boot to your app (program in a reboot button, i.e. `subprocess.call(['sudo reboot'],shell=True)`) for code updates if you are updating via ssh), see [the following link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=125129).